# c# ListView Tiles view always appears as Largeicons view

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, view, tiles

I have Listview in winforms application where I have put up toolstrip with all the view options such as Largeicons, Smallicons, List, Tiles and Details. Whenever I switch to either Tiles/ Largeicons they look the same. I cannot differentiate the view.

And I'm not using Application.EnableVisualStyles() as many sites suggest to use. For me this isn't making any difference. I'm running the app on Windows 8 OS.

Thanks!

Comment: please provide additional code and image of your problem

Comment: *To enable tile view, your application must call the `Application.EnableVisualStyles` method* - ([*MSDN*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2))